# Set Bootstrap 5 to custom REM font size

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm currently setting my font-sizes like this to make it easier with calculations in REM values:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 1.6rem; } /* 16px */
```

However, Bootstrap 5 of course uses the root value (which would be 62.5%) to calculate all of the sizes. It does have variables like `$font-size-root` and `$font-size-base` and tried to play with those trying to get it to properly calculate things.

First I tried setting the root to the HTML value and the base to the body value, but that caused the wrong calculations and setting either the base or the root to `1.6rem` or `1rem` also caused the wrong output.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure Bootstrap 5 to make it output a value matching with `32px` (computed style) when I set this for example:

```
$h1-font-size: 3.2rem;
```

That way I could simplify the calculations a lot and Bootstrap would work with the same calculations as the rest of the CSS.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions! I tried a few searches here but couldn't find much related questions sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rem` units are based on the font-size of the `html` element and the default size is 16px.

To achieve what you are doing, simple set the `font-size: 10px` to `html`. Example:

```
html { font-size: 10px; }
body { font-size: 1.6rem; } /* This will be 16px */
```

Now, doing it in Bootstrap 5 requires you to change the SCSS/CSS3 variable for body font-size. Below is an example of how to do it using CSS:

```css
html { font-size: 10px; }

:root {
  --bs-body-font-size: 1.6rem;  /* Overwrite this variable */
  font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is 1.6rem or 16px.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The only thing is, if the user has set their browser font-size to 18px for example, we would then overwrite that to 10px (and later back to 16 in the body). I was hoping to keep it dynamic based on the users' preferences (with the percentage), but I think that might not be possible then?

Bootstrap probably needs some value indeed and probably doesn't work with the percentage as it doesn't know what percentage of what it needs

Comment: It doesn’t matter what the user sets as long as you overwrite it in html {}. 

I do have to add that it’s not a recommended approach to set font size to 10px trying to standardize the rem units because it will flicker the text during first load. 

The best approach is to get used to the rem units instead of px as it allows for a more dynamic and consistent sizes when dealing with typography.

Comment: This answer is not very detailed, I am trying to do the same thing. I tried to implement your solution in a SASS file called shared.sass and it just ends up making everything huge on the screen.